# Problema com operador ternário

Tags: c++, operadores, estilo-de-codificação

Estou com problema com o operador ternário. Quero usar ele para deixar o código mais elegante pois se trata de coisa simples. Mas é como se ele não funcionasse pois não atualiza a variável. O exemplo a seguir retrata o problema:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        k= (i<5)? k++:k;
    }
    cout << k << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

O que pode ser? Pois o resultado da variável `k` é mostrado como 0.

Comment: Se você quer atribuir o valor a `k`, por quê está utilizando o operador `++`, de auto incremento? Você sabe como esse operador funciona? Ao meu ver, escrever `if (i < 5) k++;` ficaria muito mais legível que o operador ternário.

Comment: Como não dá pra saber o objetivo final, o que foi perguntado tem infinitas possibilidades. Segue mais uma pra coleção: `for(int i=0;i<10;i++) k = i > 4 ? 5 : i;`. Agora, dependendo do cenário, a mais elegante mesmo seria essa: `cout << 5 << endl;`

Comment: Para concertar, é só trocar `k++` por `++k`, mas há outras formas de corrigir essa atribuição `k=( i<5 ? k++ : k );`. Que tal `k=( i<5 ? k+1 : k );`? Ou `k+=int( i<5 );`? Ou `k+=( i<5 ? 1 : 0 );`?

Answer (score 6):

Essa expressão não vai fazer o que você quer:

```
k= (i<5)? k++:k;
```

Isso significa o seguinte:

```
Se i < 5, então:
    Avalia o k (que é zero).
    Incrementa o k, que será um.
    Atribui o valor avaliado ao k, ou seja, zero.
Senão
   Atribui k ao próprio k (não faz nada).
```

O que você queria é apenas isso:

```
if (i < 5) k++;
```

Não adianta forçar o uso do operador ternário onde ele não serve. O operador ternário é muito útil mas não é bala de prata. Não é só porque o martelo é uma ferramenta sensacional que ele deva ser usado para trocar uma lâmpada.

Comment: Se usasse o operador prefixado `++k` no ternário obteria o mesmo resultado, porém, como vc bem disse, não faz sentido usar ternário neste caso.

Answer (score 2):

Ou se quiser usar operador condicional mesmo, ainda que a performance possa ser até pior:

```
k += i < 5 ? 1 : 0;
```

Ou

```
k += i > 4 ? 5 : i; //ver comentário do Bacco acima
```

Ou ainda com provável melhor performance e menos suscetível ao [*bug* do processador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability)):

```
k += !((4 + (~i + 1)) & 0x80000000);
```

isto pode não funcionar em certas situações, então não é uma solução genérica para qualquer caso.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        k += !((4 + (~i + 1)) & 0x80000000);
    }
    cout << k << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZcPW7v). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/skwcguer-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Operator/ConditionalIncrement.cpp).

Ou

```
k += !(i / 5); //ver comentário do Victor Stafuza abaixo
```

Só testando, mas é provável que seja mais caro, divisão é uma operação complicada para o processador. Será tanto ou mais rápido se o compilador souber otimizar bem (é comum ele tentar evitar divisões).

Comment: Acho que `k += !(i / 5);` seria mais simples. De qualquer forma, isso tudo seria só para produzir código ofuscado e muito mais complexo do que o necessário.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Sim, o comentário do Bacco lá em cima é o único "certo" mesmo ;) Algo me diz que a divisão seria menos eficiente, a não ser que o compilador otimize.